# Flink same source different sinks

Tags: apache-flink, sink

Using flink I want to use a single source and  after processing through different process functions want to dump into different sinks. What should be used for this parallel computation and different sinks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```java
source = ...

stream1 = source.process(...).sinkTo(one)
stream2 = source.process(...).sinkTo(two)
```

(or use `addSink` rather than `sinkTo` if you're using the older API).

Answer (score 0):

You can use side outputs to achieve this. In your main function:

```
fun main() {
    // sinks below implement DeltaSink in my case
    val sink1 = Sink1()
    .create(...)
    val sink2 = Sink2()
    .create(...)

    val outputTag1: OutputTag<Record> = object : OutputTag<KafkaConsumerRecord>("sink1Records") {}
    val outputTag1: OutputTag<Record> = object : OutputTag<KafkaConsumerRecord>("sink2Records") {}

    val source = streamExecutionEnvironment
    .fromSource(
        ...
    )
    .process(RecordTag(outputTag1, outputTag2))

    // the Mapper classes below implement RichFlatMapFunction in my case
    source.getSideOutput(outputTag1).flatMap(Mapper1()).sinkTo(sink1)
    source.getSideOutput(outputTag2).flatMap(Mapper2()).sinkTo(sink2)
}
```

The RecordTag class used above is a custom class:

```
class RecordTag(
    val tag1: OutputTag<KafkaConsumerRecord>,
    val tag2: OutputTag<KafkaConsumerRecord>
) : ProcessFunction<KafkaConsumerRecord, RowData>() {

    @Override
    override fun processElement(record: KafkaConsumerRecord, ctx: Context, out: Collector<RowData>) {
        ctx.output(tag1, record)
        ctx.output(tag2, record)
    }
}
```

The above works in Flink 1.16